# How to get day of week from date of a month?

Tags: javascript

I want to find all dates for a specific day of week in Javascript, for example dates for all mondays in a August. I am unable to find the necessary logic for this , please help.

thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
function getDays(year, month, day) {
    var last = (new Date(year, month - 1, 0)).getDate(),
        days = {
        'sunday'    : 0,
        'monday'    : 1,
        'tuesday'   : 2,
        'wednesday' : 3,
        'thursday'  : 4,
        'friday'    : 5,
        'saturday'  : 6

    },
        dd      = days[day],
        d       = new Date(year, month - 1, 1),
        matches = [];

    for (var i=1; i<=last; i++) {
        d.setDate(i);
        if (d.getDay() == dd) matches.push(i)
    }
    return matches;
}

getDays(2014, 8, 'saturday'); // [2, 9, 16, 23, 30] <- dates that are saturday
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/g6w083t4/)

Comment: this is closest to what i want thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use Moment.js you could roll through the days of the month noting which ones correspond to the target day using the .day() function: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/

If you do a lot of date work, I heartily recommend Moment.js for its wide array of date calculations, comparisons, formatting, parsing, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The [`getDay()`](http://www.javascripture.com/Date#getDay) method returns the day of week for a given [Date](http://www.javascripture.com/Date).  It returns 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday, etc. You can check that to see if each Date in a month matches the specified day.  To get all the Mondays in a specific month, you could do:

```
var daysInMonth = function(year, month, day) {
  var currentDate = new Date(year, month);

  // Find where the first day in the month is relative to 'day'
  var delta = day - currentDate.getDay();

  // If 'day' is earlier in the week, move to the next week
  if (delta < 0) {
    delta += 7;
  }  

  var days = [];

  currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + delta);

  while (currentDate.getMonth() === month) {
    days.push(currentDate.getDate());
    currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 7);
  }
  return days;
};

console.log(daysInMonth(2014, 7 /* August */, 1 /* Monday */));
```

This code finds the first date in the month that matches the day of week you care about. Then it loops over each week adding the date of that week to the list until you reach the end of the month.